# Raspberry Pi Web Simulator Connection Error to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use the Raspberry Pi Web Simulator to send simulated device readings into my Azure IoT Hub.

I have one issue that I could not get the Raspberry Pi Web Simulator working on my work machine. I kept getting an error saying "**[IoT hub Client] Connect error: undefined**", but I got everything working from home using the same device connection string and I am able to see messages in IoT Hub.

What am I missing?

I use IE at work and the work machines have to use a proxy to connect to the internet. Is this causing the issue?

Any help is very much appreciated.

URL for Raspberry Pi Web Simulator - https://azure-samples.github.io/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/#GetStarted

Comment: Could be a firewall blocking the traffic? It seems to be using MQTT by default. You could try using HTTPS instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device-http.

Comment: Not sure I can install anything on the work computer, but I will try this. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this issue may be caused by the proxy environment. You can track a known issue([#17](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer/issues/17)) on GitHub. And you can test it with not in proxy environment.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll just use my phone to kick-off the simulator :)